# Showing that the powers of a root of the p-th cyclotomic polynomial are distinct roots thereof.

Tags: field-theory

Suppose $p$ is a prime number and $p(x) = x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + ... + x + 1$ is the p-th cyclotomic polynomial and $\gamma$ is a root thereof, so that $p(\gamma) = 0$.  I need to show that the following set: $\{\gamma, \gamma^2, \gamma^3, ..., \gamma^{p-1}\}$ consists of distinct roots of $p(x)$.

So basically I want to show that for some $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$, $a_1\gamma + a_2\gamma^2 + ... + a_{p-1}\gamma^{p-1} = 0$ implies that all of the $a_i$'s are zero.

However, this is where I get stuck.

Comment: You forgot to mention that $p$ is prime, I suppose? For if $p=4$, we see that $\gamma=-1$ is a root of $p(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$, but $\gamma^2=1$ is not.

Comment: Yes, indeed p is supposed to be prime, I thought that naming it $p$ as opposed to $n$ or some other letter would be enough.  I just added it to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\gamma$ also is a root of $(x-1)p(x)=x^p-1$.
Then for any $k$, $\gamma^k$ is also a root of $x^p-1$, for $(\gamma^k)^p=(\gamma^p)^k=1$. So up to now the numbers $\gamma,\gamma^2,\ldots, \gamma^{p-1}$ are all either roots of $p(x)$ or $=1$.

Assume $\gamma^k=1$ with $1\le k<p$. Then $\gamma$ is also a root of $x^k-1$, hence also of $\gcd(x^p-1,x^k-1)=x^{\gcd(p,k)}-1$. It is about time to use the fact that $p$ is **prime:** From it we get  $\gcd(p,k)=1$, hence $\gamma^k=1$ implies  $\gamma=1$. But $p(1)=p-1\ne0$.
So now we now that the $\gamma^k$, $1\le k\le p-1$ are in fact roots of $p(x)$.

Assume $\gamma^j=\gamma^k$ with $1\le j<k<p$. Then $\gamma^{k-1}=1$, which we have just seen is not possible. 
We conclude that the $\gamma^k$, $1\le k<p$, are distinct.

In summary: $\gamma,\gamma^2,\ldots,\gamma^{p-1}$ are distinct roots of $p(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

The roots solve the equation $$x^p-1=0$$ Since the derivate of $x^p-1$ is $px^{p-1}$, you can see easily that $x^p-1$ has distinct roots.

Therefore the roots of the cyclotomic polynomials are distinct as well.

Comment: I see, that seems much simpler than what I was trying to do.  So basically since the derivative is a single term, it's clear that all the roots must be distinct (nothing to show), but how does that imply that the poly $x^p - 1$ has distinct roots as well? I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: You seem to mix two things. The derivate has only the multiple root $0$, but this is not a root of $x^p-1$. This shows that $x^p-1$ cannot have multiple roots, otherwise the derivate would share at least one root with the function. The root of $px^{p-1}$ is not single, but what is right : The derivate has a single value as a root.

Comment: I see, that makes sense.

Comment: @Peter You do not use the (unstated by the OP) fact that $p$ is prime. For $p=4$, we might have $\gamma=-1$ and then fail because $\gamma^2$ is not a root of $x^3+x^2+x+1$ and because $\gamma^3$ and $\gamma^1$ are equal.

Comment: Should I delete the qeustion, or add this condition ?